# Connecting NiFi with Sybase database erroring

Tags: apache-nifi, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

Could you please help me with the correct URL format to connect to Sybase using the DBCP connection pool of NiFi?

The URL format that I have tried is - jdbc:sybase:Tds://host:port

I keep getting this error - failed to create Poolable Connection Factory. Incorrect URL format.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which jdbc driver you are using?

Comment: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbprogramming/url-using-jdbc.html

Comment: Hi @daggett - I'm using com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
I'm using the same URL format as mentioned in the above doc but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: your url in question a bit different. should be without slash: `jdbc:sybase:Tds:host:port`

Comment: @daggett - tried without the slash too and I get the same error.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace from log file.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: @markp-fuso - we're using ASE version 16.0